# Why update mysql query run slow

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL Tabe "STG_S_CUST" which contains a lot of rows (up to 1.5 million) and another table "S_CUST" which contains a lot of rows.
when I'm executing the following Update query, it's very slow, it takes too much time.

```
UPDATE STG_S_CUST AS STG
INNER JOIN S_CUST AS ST ON STG.SRC_NM=ST.SRC_NM
AND STG.SRC_KEY = ST.SRC_KEY
SET UPDATE_IND = 1,
STG.S_ID = ST.S_ID,
STG.M_ID = ST.M_ID
WHERE STG.PROCESSED_IND = 0
```

The problem is, that I get a Timeout-Exception unable to execute SQL.

```
EXPLAIN UPDATE STG_S_CUST AS STG
INNER JOIN S_CUST AS ST ON STG.SRC_NM=ST.SRC_NM
AND STG.SRC_KEY = ST.SRC_KEY
SET UPDATE_IND = 1,
STG.S_ID = ST.S_ID,
STG.M_ID = ST.M_ID
WHERE STG.PROCESSED_IND = 0

Result:

id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE          ST      ALL     NULL             NULL    NULL       NULL    10479   NULL
1   SIMPLE          STG     ALL     NULL             NULL    NULL       NULL    159334  Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
```

here's an abbreviated version of the create tables

**STG_S_CUST :**

```
  CREATE TABLE `STG_S_CUST` (
 `STG_ID` int(14) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `STG_DATE` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON  UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `SRC_KEY` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `SRC_NM` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `M_ID` int(14) DEFAULT NULL,
 `S_ID` int(14) DEFAULT NULL,
 `PROCESSED_IND` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `THREAD_ID` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
 `UPDATE_IND` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`STG_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=171998 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**S_CUST :**

```
 CREATE TABLE `S_CUST` (
 `S_ID` int(14) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `SRC_KEY` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `SRC_NM` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `M_ID` int(14) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`S_ID`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10803 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this would be so slow and how to speed it up ?
Could anyone help me here for optimization?

Comment: "up to a 15 lakhs" - can you please convert for us poor english-only speakers ;)

Comment: Also - (just covering all bases) have you looked at the optimisation section in the MySql docs? eg https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimization.html

Comment: @TarynEast hi 15 lakhs -> 1.5 Million

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu you are Incorrect! 10 lakh(lacs) ->1 Million So 15 lakhs -> 1.5 Million

Comment: You can use EXPLAIN EXTENDED for more info and warning.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-extended.html

Comment: Also, Caps Lock is great, isn't it?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty, thanx, your solution worked. We have made little change in your index. We have removed index on PROCESSED_IND and SRC_NM as those columns have very few values. So we have applied index only on STG_S_CUST.SRC_KEY. Can you please add an answer, so that I can accept it.

Comment: @SandeshNavale added as answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some indexing for making the select part faster while doing the join update, start with adding the following indexes

```
alter table STG_S_CUST add index PROCESSED_IND_idx(PROCESSED_IND); 
alter table STG_S_CUST add index SRC_idx(SRC_NM,SRC_KEY); 
alter table S_CUST add index SRC_NM_idx(SRC_NM)
```

Take a backup of the tables first before applying the indexes

Comment: thanx, your solution worked. We have made little change in your index. We have removed index on PROCESSED_IND and SRC_NM as those columns have very few values. So we have applied index only on STG_S_CUST.SRC_KEY.

Comment: Can you please tell me, why you did not suggest to create index on `S_CUST.SRC_KEY` as query contains this where clause `STG.SRC_KEY = ST.SRC_KEY`?

Comment: @NamanGala good catch you should actually need those indexes which are used in the joining clause that would make the possible number of row scan lower by the optimizer. However note that if the row number is less optimizer may scan all the values instead of going through index lookup.

Comment: Thanks, so if both the tables have large number of rows, then index should be applied to both the tables. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: Well theoretically you should not worry about the number of rows, just need to make sure that the joining keys are indexed and most importantly they are of same datatype, and indexes for `where` and `order by`. If your query is almost same elsewhere using some common key in the where clause better would be to use covering index (composite index), rest will be taken care by optimizer which one is best depending on the data size.